# How do I redirect domains to different ports on the same server?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, port, portforwarding

I want to use different softwares in one Ubuntu server and reach them with different domains and same(80) port. The softwares is working in different ports in local. For example:

Soft1: example.com:80 -> localhost:9000

Soft2: deneme.com:80 -> localhost:6555

What can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting up virtual hosts/servers on your web server. Since you didn't mention any web server, I'm gonna go with NGINX.

So go ahead and follow [this guide to setup NGINX](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04). For your case, you'll be creating two configuration files in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` for your domains `example.com` and `deneme.com` with the following configurations:

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80
    server_name  example.com

    location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
    }
}
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/deneme.com`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80
    server_name  deneme.com

    location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:6555/;
    }
}
```

Now point your domain to your server IP and you should be seeing your application.

Comment: Glad to help :)